# Ruby web spider & search engine library

Tags: ruby, search, rubygems, web-crawler

I'm looking for a Ruby library or gem (or set of gems) which will not only do spidering, but also collect the data into, say, a database, and allow basic searches on the data (i.e. a typical web search).

I've found several spidering libraries, so that part seems well covered (I was going to try Anemone first), but I can't find anything that will take the spidered data and allow querying on it.  For lack of an existing one, I was going to write something myself with Anemone.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That [blog post](http://blog.saush.com/2009/03/17/write-an-internet-search-engine-with-200-lines-of-ruby-code/) might give you some pointers. Also, look into [ferret](http://www.davebalmain.com/) for the search part.

Answer (score 1):

there is a ruby gem may help you:
http://spidr.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of [great stuff](http://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=rb&q=spider&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1) on github.com

Comment: as of 2020 above url doesn't work as expected. this url should be used instead: https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&q=spider&type=Repositories